# Случайное изображение из папки, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Все что я нашел:

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
  
 var a=Math.round(Math.random()*4)
 image = new Array();
 linked=new Array();
 linked[0]="http://www.cyberforum.ru/"
 linked[1]="http://www.google/"
 linked[2]="http://arena-tournament.com/ladder/WOTLK/"
 linked[3]="http://translate.google.com/"
 image[0]="img/logo.jpg"
 image[1]="img/logo.jpg"
 image[2]="img/logo2.jpg"
 image[3]="img/logo3.jpg"
 document.write ("<a href="+linked[a]+"><img src="+image[a]+"></a>");
 </script>
```

Но мне нужно при каждом обновлении страницы показывать случайное изображение *.jpg из папки img/, изображение в папке может быть разное количество

Comment: and i dont need links, just one link with random image from folder:
<a id="click" href="$(link-login-only)?dst=http://pizza-nys.com.ua/&amp;username=T-$(mac-esc)"> RANDOM IMAGE </a>

Comment: i make a random login page for HOTSPOT using mikrotik router

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random()*(arr.length))` - random index of array

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пожалуйста, переведите вопрос на русский язык. это можно сделать, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.